# How would I make some circle in G- shape?

Tags: fonts, logo, typography

I would like to make this logo but I don't know how to put circle in G shape either in U.
Also is there any way to put circle in rounded - ractangle tool?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Harry! Can you tell us something more on your efforts and your tools? I.e., what king of graphic software are you using?

Comment: Are you really asking how to draw a circle? Your sample is merely outlines of glyphs with circles *manually* drawn and placed inside the outline.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned no software, I'll assume you are using a vector image editor, which would be the best software in which to create a logo.

This example below was created in Inkscape, and although it's not a tutorial, the basic steps are covered. This could also be done similarly in other vector software such as Adobe Illustrator, Affinity Designer, CoralDraw etc.

1. A large circle is drawn, and a smaller circle is positioned to intersect the path of the larger circle - use guides and snapping to get them to align exactly
2. A second inner large circle is drawn, again using guides and snapping to get the exact intersection
3. The smaller circle is moved to the 2 o'clock position
4. I drop another guide to help me position another copy of the smaller circle at the 4 o'clock position
5. I edit the larger circles by removing sections between the two smaller circles
6. Another two copies of the smaller circles are added and moved into position using the guides and snapping
7. Straight connecting lines are added, snapping helps get the exact positioning

[image]